# ProFTPd MySQL setup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, ftp-server, proftpd

I'm trying to install ProFTPd with MySQL on Ubuntu server 11.10 64-bit. But I cannot login, always showing 'Login Incorrect'

This is my **sql.conf** file:

```
# add the following lines to the file (don't need to remove comments from it)

DefaultRoot ~

# The passwords in MySQL are encrypted using CRYPT
SQLBackend     mysql
SQLEngine on
SQLAuthTypes            Plaintext Crypt
SQLAuthenticate         users* groups*

# used to connect to the database
# databasename@host database_user user_password
SQLConnectInfo  ftp@localhost proftpd password

# Here we tell ProFTPd the names of the database columns in the "usertable"
# we want it to interact with. Match the names with those in the db
SQLUserInfo     ftpuser userid passwd uid gid homedir shell

# Here we tell ProFTPd the names of the database columns in the "grouptable"
# we want it to interact with. Again the names match with those in the db
SQLGroupInfo    ftpgroup groupname gid members

# set min UID and GID - otherwise these are 999 each
SQLMinID        500

# create a user's home directory on demand if it doesn't exist
SQLHomedirOnDemand on

# Update count every time user logs in
SQLLog PASS updatecount
SQLNamedQuery updatecount UPDATE "count=count+1, accessed=now() WHERE userid='%u'" ftpuser

# Update modified everytime user uploads or deletes a file
SQLLog  STOR,DELE modified
SQLNamedQuery modified UPDATE "modified=now() WHERE userid='%u'" ftpuser

# User quotas
# ===========
QuotaEngine on
QuotaDirectoryTally on
QuotaDisplayUnits Mb
QuotaShowQuotas on

SQLNamedQuery get-quota-limit SELECT "name, quota_type, per_session, limit_type, bytes_in_avail, bytes_out_avail, bytes_xfer_avail, files_in_avail, files_out_avail, files_xfer_avail FROM ftpquotalimits WHERE name = '%{0}' AND quota_type = '%{1}'"

SQLNamedQuery get-quota-tally SELECT "name, quota_type, bytes_in_used, bytes_out_used, bytes_xfer_used, files_in_used, files_out_used, files_xfer_used FROM ftpquotatallies WHERE name = '%{0}' AND quota_type = '%{1}'"

SQLNamedQuery update-quota-tally UPDATE "bytes_in_used = bytes_in_used + %{0}, bytes_out_used = bytes_out_used + %{1}, bytes_xfer_used = bytes_xfer_used + %{2}, files_in_used = files_in_used + %{3}, files_out_used = files_out_used + %{4}, files_xfer_used = files_xfer_used + %{5} WHERE name = '%{6}' AND quota_type = '%{7}'" ftpquotatallies

SQLNamedQuery insert-quota-tally INSERT "%{0}, %{1}, %{2}, %{3}, %{4}, %{5}, %{6}, %{7}" ftpquotatallies

QuotaLimitTable sql:/get-quota-limit
QuotaTallyTable sql:/get-quota-tally/update-quota-tally/insert-quota-tally

RootLogin off
RequireValidShell off
SQLNamedQuery userquota SELECT "IF ((SELECT (@availmbytes:=ROUND((`bytes_in_avail`/1048576),2)) FROM `ftpquotalimits` WHERE `name`='%u') = 0, \"No user quota applies.\", CONCAT(\"User quota: Used \", (SELECT (@usedmbytes:=ROUND((`bytes_in_used`/1048576),2)) FROM `ftpquotatallies` WHERE `name`='%u'), \"MB from \", @availmbytes, \"MB. You have \", ROUND(@availmbytes-@usedmbytes,2), \"MB available space.\"))"

SQLShowInfo   LIST    "226" "%{userquota}"
PassivePorts 60000 65000
```

is there anything wrong with those codes??
Does SQLConnectInfo username and password need quote??

Comment: What does [ProFTPD debug logging](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Debugging.html), debug level 10, show?

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you try to follow this manual.

Ubuntu 12:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-proftpd-with-a-mysql-backend-on-ubuntu-12-10

Ubuntu 14:
https://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-hosting-with-proftpd-and-mysql-incl-quota-on-ubuntu-14.04-lts-p2